# How to start new activity and wait some time and start another one?

Tags: java, android

This below code to start activity "welcome1" and execute Thread() Then start another activity called "gps"
but when it executes the gps activity running without running activity welcome1

how can to start welcome1 and wait some time then start activity gps

Code

```
public class welcome1 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork()
            .penaltyLog().build());
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome1);

    final TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    final TextView person = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    final Intent v = getIntent();
   final String abt = v.getStringExtra("frist_name");
    Runnable myRun=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int  s=0;s<2;s++){
                final int finalI =s;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       if (finalI==0)
                       {
                           welcome.setText(welcome2);
                                person.setText(abt);
                       }
                        if (finalI==1)
                                welcome.setText(steps);
                    }
                });
                synchronized (this) {
                    try {
                        wait(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    Thread T=new Thread(myRun);
    T.start();
    String number = v.getStringExtra("mobile_number");
    String pwd = v.getStringExtra("pass");

    Intent d = new Intent(getBaseContext(),gps.class);
    d.putExtra("mobile_number",number);
    d.putExtra("pass", pwd);

    startActivity(d);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`startActivity(Intent)` is called right after the `Thread T` starts. Thus it ignores the `Thread T` you created and just runs in the UI thread.

Correct code to do what you want is this:

```
public class welcome1 extends Activity {

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork()
            .penaltyLog().build());
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome1);

    final TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    final TextView person = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    final Intent v = getIntent();    final String abt = v.getStringExtra("frist_name");
    Runnable myRun=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int  s=0;s<2;s++){
                final int finalI =s;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       if (finalI==0)
                       {
                           welcome.setText(welcome2);
                                person.setText(abt);
                       }
                        if (finalI==1)
                                welcome.setText(steps);
                    }
                });
                try {
                    wait(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String number = v.getStringExtra("mobile_number");
                        String pwd = v.getStringExtra("pass");

                        Intent d = new Intent(getBaseContext(),gps.class);
                        d.putExtra("mobile_number",number);
                        d.putExtra("pass", pwd);
                        startActivity(d);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };

    Thread T=new Thread(myRun);
    T.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with a Handler?

Just create a Runnable which starts the next activity and run like this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(yourRunnable,timeinmillis)
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste this code into your oncreate() method:

```
//This will wait for 10secs before launching the gps activity
        Handler h = new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(welcome1.this, Gps.class));
            }
        }, 10000);
```

Then run your code, it should work now.